# Зависает программа Java

Tags: java, cmd

У меня есть код

```
public void runFile() throws IOException {
             Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String[] cmd = new String[3];
        cmd[0] = "cmd.exe" ;
        cmd[1] = "/C";
        cmd[2] = "java " +  saveFile.toString();
        Process proc = runtime.exec(cmd);

        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            textAreaConsole.appendText(line);
        }
    }
```

Но моя программа зависает при открытие cmd (если закрыть cmd то все продолжает работать)
скорее всего это изза while. Можно ли этот while выполнить в другом потоке например? И как это сделать?

Comment: Видимо, этот код вызывается как действие в треде EDT (event dispatch thread), что и блокирует пользовательский интерфейс. Нужно вызывать в другом треде. Например, через прямолинейное использование `Thread`.

Comment: как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void runFile() throws IOException {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String[] cmd = new String[3];
        cmd[0] = "cmd.exe" ;
        cmd[1] = "/C";
        cmd[2] = "java " +  saveFile.toString();
        Process proc = runtime.exec(cmd);
        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        new thread().start();
    }
    class thread extends Thread {
        public void run(){
            String line;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    if (!((line = br.readLine()) != null)) break;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                textAreaConsole.appendText(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

вот как я решил эту проблему!

Comment: Как-то слишком кучеряво: `!((line = br.readLine()) != null)`, хватило бы `(line = br.readLine()) == null`